# Format JSON ojects for Ember / drill-down / serialize / adapter

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I'm pulling some JSON with ajax (*because I can't get past CORS with my limited understanding/lack of useful examples/ of the RESTAdapter...*) - and I'm getting these nested objects. I need an array of the 'book' - but I'm unsure of how to format this JSON so that it's readable.

### routes/books.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ajax from 'ic-ajax';

var libraryThingApi = "http://www.librarything.com/api_getdata.php?";

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function() {

    var libraryData = ajax({
      url: libraryThingApi + "userid=F.L.O.W.",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    });

    console.log(libraryData);
    return libraryData;
  }

});
```

### what is returned

```
Promise
  _id: 47
  _label: "ic-ajax: unwrap raw ajax response"
  ...
  _result: Object
    books: Object
      111333266: Object
        title: "a book title"
      111730480: Object
        title: "a book title"
    settings: Object
      theuser: "F.L.O.W."
      more_things: "etc"
```

```
{
  books: {
    111601539: {
      book_id: "111601539",
      title: "Rosie Revere, Engineer",
      author_fl: "Andrea Beaty",
      copies: 1
    },
    121604536: {
      book_id: "121604536",
      title: "Ember for people who aren't core.",
      author_fl: "No author",
      copies: "This book does not exist"
    }
  },
  settings: {
     theuser: "sheriffderek"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just grabbing raw json, you can use it really however you'd like. It then just becomes a matter of how you want to access the data in your route's template.

Ember's model hook is promise aware so you are correct to simply return the promise. The fulfilled value of that promise is then what you'll be interested in for your template. Thus if the fulfilled value is something like this:

```
{
  books: [
    {id: 1, title: "some title", nested_data: {author: "some author"}},
    {id: 2, title: "another title", nested_data: {author: "another author"}},
  ]
}
```

Then inside the template for your route you can access the fulfilled value from your returned promise inside the model hook. Pre Ember 1.10 (deprecated later in the 1.x series) you can each through your books in your route's template like this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each book in model.books}}
    <li>{{book.title}} by {{book.nested_data.author}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Ember 1.10 and beyond introduces block params for each statements:

```
<ul>
  {{#each model.books as |book|}}
    <li>{{book.title}} by {{book.nested_data.author}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Read the information about Ember 1.10 release [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html).

Comment: So, I think that the problem might be that there aren't conventional id's in this response. (I'm on the most recent releases of Ember and EmberCLI btw) -  I can get access to `{{model.books.116428944.title}}` but in loop, I get `The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {116428942: [object Object], ....`  I'm just punching in the dark here...

Comment: It looks like I have to leapfrog over the nested object or something. Added some more info - if you have time to take a look.

Comment: Indeed, what you are trying to iterate over is not an array. You could transform it to an array (either on the server where the JSON is rendered, or in javascript after you've received the JSON) Do you have control over how the backend is serving the JSON? That would be the best place to transform the data to be an array.

Comment: The JSON is coming from "librarything"'s API... which is limited. ::: http://www.librarything.com/services/

Comment: If you're able to alter the way the library is serving up the JSON then that is the advised path IMO. However, it is not uncommon that people do not have control over their backend, so you can massage the data after it comes in. Where you do this is up to you, but essentially after you make the ajax request, transform the response the way you want and return the transformation in your model hook.